# How to add 2 array of variable length with user input in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
    arrayInput1[];
    arrayInput2[];
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Compare and add the corresponding array elements of variable length

Comment: Your question is not clear as it stands currently.

Answer (score 1):

It's missing some informations to help you properly, but if you follow the syntax

> <*type*> [ ]  = new <*type*> [length]

with:

- *type* being what your array is storing, such as **int**, **String**, **double**, etc
- name being your array name
- length is the array length, it calls for an integer number. You can replace here for one of your instances of **Scanner** calling some function to read the next input e.g next()

Just be sure to declare your array after the scanners, if you're setting the length in the moment of variable declaration, or when you compile the system is going trow an error that they don't exist in the moment of the function call

Answer (score 0):

Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] arrayInput1 = new String[sc1.nextInt()];
String[] arrayInput2 = new String[sc2.nextInt()];